# Use Selenium to get Strava Leaderboard Table

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I have the code below, where I am attempting to get a table from this [page](https://www.strava.com/clubs/roosevelt-island-dc-parkrun). I want to scrape the "This Week's Leaderboard," but I am having trouble actually getting the table out of it. What's the best way to get the table? I just get the HTML output, and really don't want to `regex` it all together.

```
### Libraries/packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from functools import reduce
import smtplib



### Function 1
def strava_page():

    # in this example, I'm using a public group. In my code there are extra steps to login, which I omit here
    urllist = ['https://www.strava.com/login',
               'https://www.strava.com/clubs/roosevelt-island-dc-parkrun']

    return urllist


### Function 2
def strava_login(urllist):

    # open login page
    #url = urllist[0]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"/Users/user/Documents/chromedriver")
    #driver.get(url)
    #login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_form"]/div[2]/a')
    #login.click()

    # input username login 
    #emailbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
    #emailbox.send_keys('user') 
    #emailbox.send_keys(u'\ue007')

    # input password
    #passbox = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext")
    #passbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
    #passbox.send_keys('password')
    #passbox.send_keys(u'\ue007')

    # navigate to Strava group page
    mayrun = driver.get(urllist[1])
    mayrun

    # get "This Week's Leaderboard"
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.view > div.page.container > div:nth-child(4) > div.spans11 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.leaderboard > table > tbody')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Request Timed Out...Idiot")
    table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.view > div.page.container > div:nth-child(4) > div.spans11 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.leaderboard > table > tbody').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(table)


    driver.close()

    return table

### Call functions
one = strava_page()
two = strava_login(one)
two
```

I get this in return, but have tried all sorts of `xpath` and `css selector` paths to try and get the table itself, plus some `pd.read_html()` or `pd.DataFrame()` failed attempts:

```
<td class="rank">1</td>
<td class="athlete">
<div class="avatar avatar-athlete avatar-sm">
<a class="avatar-content" href="/athletes/34781197">
<div class="avatar-img-wrapper avatar-default">

<img alt="Chi H." src="/assets/avatar/athlete/medium.png" title="Chi H.">
</div>
</a>
</div>
<a class="athlete-name minimal" href="/athletes/34781197">
Chi H.
</a>
</td>
<td class="distance highlighted-column">86.3 <abbr class="unit short" title="kilometers">km</abbr></td>
<td class="num-activities">8</td>
<td class="longest-activity">
42.2 <abbr class="unit short" title="kilometers">km</abbr>
</td>
<td class="average-pace">7:37 <abbr class="unit short" title="minutes per kilometer">/km</abbr></td>
<td class="elev-gain">528 <abbr class="unit short" title="meters">m</abbr></td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="rank">2</td>
<td class="athlete">
<div class="avatar avatar-athlete avatar-sm">
<a class="avatar-content" href="/athletes/1802199">
<div class="avatar-img-wrapper avatar-default">

<img alt="Andrew P." src="/assets/avatar/athlete/medium.png" title="Andrew P.">
</div>
</a>
</div>
<a class="athlete-name minimal" href="/athletes/1802199">
Andrew P.
</a>
</td>
<td class="distance highlighted-column">74.6 <abbr class="unit short" title="kilometers">km</abbr></td>
<td class="num-activities">7</td>
<td class="longest-activity">
22.5 <abbr class="unit short" title="kilometers">km</abbr>
</td>
<td class="average-pace">5:55 <abbr class="unit short" title="minutes per kilometer">/km</abbr></td>
<td class="elev-gain">3,685 <abbr class="unit short" title="meters">m</abbr></td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="rank">3</td>
<td class="athlete">
<div class="avatar avatar-athlete avatar-sm">
<a class="avatar-content" href="/athletes/4702810">
<div class="avatar-img-wrapper avatar-default">

<img alt="Sarah Reese B." src="/assets/avatar/athlete/medium.png" title="Sarah Reese B.">
</div>
</a>
</div>
<a class="athlete-name minimal" href="/athletes/4702810">
Sarah Reese B.
</a>
</td>
<td class="distance highlighted-column">70.1 <abbr class="unit short" title="kilometers">km</abbr></td>
<td class="num-activities">11</td>
<td class="longest-activity">
12.8 <abbr class="unit short" title="kilometers">km</abbr>
</td>
<td class="average-pace">4:49 <abbr class="unit short" title="minutes per kilometer">/km</abbr></td>
<td class="elev-gain">298 <abbr class="unit short" title="meters">m</abbr></td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="rank">4</td>
<td class="athlete">
<div class="avatar avatar-athlete avatar-sm">
<a class="avatar-content" href="/athletes/1284779">
<div class="avatar-img-wrapper avatar-default">

Etc.

Etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, it would be easier to just to call the service and get all the data in json format. However that may need a cookie to make that request. I have tried to use selenium to scrape the table title and rows -

```
driver.get('https://www.strava.com/clubs/roosevelt-island-dc-parkrun-215283')

#Find the Search Button and return all search results
table_headers =[]
for items in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaderboard']/table/thead//th"):
    table_headers.append(items.text)

print(table_headers)
table_rows = []
myrow = []
totalrows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaderboard']/table/tbody//tr"))

for i in range(totalrows):
    myrow.clear()
    for items in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaderboard']/table/tbody//tr["+str(i+1)+"]/td"):
        myrow.append(items.text)

    table_rows.append(myrow)
    print(myrow)
print(table_rows)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
['Rank', 'Athlete', 'Distance', 'Runs', 'Longest', 'Avg. Pace', 'Elev. Gain']
['1', 'Chi H.', '86.3 km', '8', '42.2 km', '7:37 /km', '528 m']
['2', 'Lokesh M.', '47.5 km', '4', '13.2 km', '5:28 /km', '1,046 m']
['3', 'Sarah Reese B.', '47.5 km', '9', '12.8 km', '4:45 /km', '168 m']
['4', 'SP R.', '46.2 km', '3', '20.2 km', '4:40 /km', '128 m']
['5', 'Sharada P.', '41.4 km', '4', '12.4 km', '8:46 /km', '--']
```

Comment: This is great! How do I get it to stop repeating the last row over and over? E.g., say row 5 in your output, repeats over and over. Or maybe the right question is why does it do that in my output?

Comment: i am able to print all 100 rows. please double check your code and output